# Embedding matplotlib inside Qt ActiveX component

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt, activex

I'm attempting to embed some `matplotlib` figures inside of an ActiveX component using [Active Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-index.html) on Windows 7, having already successfully embedded `matplotlib` figures inside of a regular Qt project.

Using the [Simple](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-activeqt-simple-example.html) and [Menus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-activeqt-menus-example.html) examples from the Qt docs as a reference, I have managed to embed a Python interpreter in an ActiveX component and run some basic Python code that constructs `QWidget` objects using `PyQt5`.

This all works fine and I am able to use PyQt to construct parts of the interface of the ActiveX component, and send signals between widgets created with either Python and c++ etc. with no problems. I can even create matplotlib `FigureCanvas` objects using the `PyQt5` backend. However, as soon as I try to embed a `FigureCanvas` that has had a subplot added to it, my ActiveX component crashes with a generic Visual C++ Runtime Error:

> The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unsual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

To make matters worse, I am unable to run a debug build because the debug build of `libpython` requires debug builds of all compiled extension module dependencies to be built, and I haven't had any luck with building `numpy`/`scipy` from scratch.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could be causing this crash? I wonder whether it has something to do with the threading model used by COM objects or the Python GIL but I don't know enough about the subjects. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. The examples I was following create an out-of-process ActiveX server. Switching to an in-process server stopped the crashes.

From the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-server.html):

> To build an in-process server, use a .pro file like this:
>
> ```
> TEMPLATE = lib
> QT += axserver
> CONFIG  += dll
>
> DEF_FILE = qaxserver.def
> RC_FILE  = qaxserver.rc
> ...
> ```